# wpf - How to use Path, ElementName with markup extension

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wpf-controls, binding, wpfdatagrid

I am using [this markup extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no/841894#841894)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Something" 
                    Binding="{controls:SwitchBinding Something, Yes, No}" />
```

It all works fine, except that now I need to specify Path and Element Name for the Binding.(maybe even 'mode')

I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
Binding="{controls:SwitchBinding {Binding Path=SelectedItem.SystemDefined, ElementName=dgrdStatementBlocks}, Yes, No}"
```

Can somebody please point me to the correct way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you do this??

```
Binding="{controls:SwitchBinding {Binding Path=SelectedItem.SystemDefined, ElementName=dgrdStatementBlocks}, Yes, No}
```

Try the following:

```
Binding="{controls:SwitchBinding Path=SelectedItem.SystemDefined, ElementName=dgrdStatementBlocks, ValueIfTrue=Yes, ValueIfFalse=No}
```

### Edit:

I tried this in a sample `WPF(.Net4)` (not `Silverlight`) application. And the following worked:

```
<CheckBox Name="CheckBox1"
            IsChecked="True" />
<TextBlock Name="TextBlock1"
            Text="{local:SwitchBinding ElementName=CheckBox1, Path=IsChecked, ValueIfTrue=Yes, ValueIfFalse=No}" />
```

Comment: Thankyou. But, It didn't work since the constructors to `Binding` do not accept 'ElementName' since its a property which i tried setting in another constructor as `this.ElementName = elementName;` and called `:base(path)` just as before.

Comment: Notice that I only use named parameters to avoid use of parametrized constructor. Did you try that exact code?