# C# 'if' Binding value

Tags: c#, data-binding, if-statement

I've got a list view that is populated by a Binding, on a class named `House`.

**Here's an example of my code:**

```
<DataTemplate DataType="house">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding sold_status}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, one of my variable names is `sold_status`.  This is a `bool`.

I want to show either "SOLD" or "NOT SOLD" for `1` and `0` respectively.

Is it possible to fashion an if statement based on the value?

So just so that you can visualise what I want to achieve:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="house">
    <TextBlock Text="({Binding sold_status} == 1) 'SOLD' else 'NOT SOLD'" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to create a Style with DataTriggers in to set the properties as needed.  You could also use a converter, but changing UI control properties based on underlying data is exactly what triggers/styles are all about.

..In fact, I can see you're basically 'converting' sold_status to a bit of text.  For that, use a converter.  I'll post a quick example..

See the top answer here: [WPF: Display a bool value as "Yes" / "No"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no) - it has an example converter class you could repurpose.

Comment: +1 - A converter is definately the way to go. In fact this is such a common problem with bools that I'm surprised there's not a VS code snippet for it.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the IValueConverter interface for an example. Implement the Convert method to return the text you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a value [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_conversion).

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this would be to use a converter. Keep the binding as you have done in your first example then have the converter return a string with "Sold" if true etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a DataTrigger. It's quite simple and doesn't require separate converter.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="house">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Status" Text="SOLD" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{sold_status}" Value="False">
              <Setter TargetName="Status" Property="Text" Value="NOT SOLD"/>
         </DataTrigger>

    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```