# In a DataGrid, how do I make a boolean be represented as "yes/no" instead of a checkbox?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, .net-4.0, datagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF: Display a bool value as “Yes” / “No”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no)

I'm writing a WPF program in VB.Net 2010 (.NET 4.0) that uses data binding against a simple class that is an ObservableCollection of another simple class I've written. So far I have a DataGrid that shows the information and I can add and remove items as necessary, but I seem to be stumbling with a fairly basic concept:

How do I display data in some way other than the default behaviours that the various DataGrid columns allow?

I have a boolean called "reversed" in my original class, let's call it "x". I would like the DataGrid displaying the ObservableCollection of "x" to display "Yes" or "No" under the Reversed column instead of a checkbox that is checked or unchecked (DataGridCheckBoxColumn).

Is there a nice way to do this or am I wasting my time? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(string))]
public class FlopBoolean : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (bool)value return "yes"; 
        return "no";
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

       return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. I'm not using CS so I had to do a tiny bit of thinking to write this in VB. I didn't find any equivalent to your first line where it specifies which types the converter implements, but in spite of that it does the job.

Comment: That first line can be wrong and it still works so I don't think it matters.

Comment: I actually read somewhere a little after my first comment that the first line specifies the conversion type as additional data for a "future version" of the development environment and it's not used at all right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of your objects, which is binded to DataView or DataGridView, you can create a property and display that property in the datagrid. Example:

```
Public Class Example
     <Browsable(False)> Public Property isLinked As Boolean

     <DisplayName("Linked")> Public ReadOnly Property LinkedDisplay As String
        Get
            If isLinked Then
                Return "Yes"
            Else
                Return "No"
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

The drawback of it is that you won't be able to edit this column on the datagridview.

Comment: This worked for me too (I also tried @Blam 's answer). This version is  simpler to implement, but, just as a thought, it also seems less "polished" since you have to modify the underlying data structure to help change the way it's displayed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Partially agree. It is a bit messier from that point of view but it makes some other bits of the code cleaner as you don't have to write any additional code to display/format your results.