# WPF Style Triggers on DataGrid being overwritten by binding

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpfdatagrid, wpf-style

I found a way to convert a boolean to a yes/no instead of True/False in a wpf datagrid using: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089837/1646494, however this column is not sortable once this is done. My code is below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header=" Consolidated Company " IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lRollupCompany}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lRollupCompany}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Trying to get the sorting to work again just makes the column revert back to showing True/False...

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Consolidated Company " Binding="{Binding lRollupCompany}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="100">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,0,5,0" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lRollupCompany}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding lRollupCompany}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve a converter?

Comment: use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

Comment: @Jon, did you try setting `<DataGridTextColumn  ... SortMemberPath="lRollupCompany"/>`?

Comment: @dkozl Ugh, thanks. Post an answer and I'll up-vote it for ya. That fixed the problem (which I suppose is just a vast unfamiliarity with WPF controls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change by what given `DataGrid` column is sorted you can use [`DataGridColumn.SortMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.sortmemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a property name, or a period-delimited hierarchy of property names, that indicates the member to sort by

so in your XAML you can do

```
<DataGridTextColumn  ... SortMemberPath="lRollupCompany"/>
```