# Binding to Bool, displaying Text

Tags: c#, wpf

As title says, I want to bind a List view to an List

X has multiple boolean property and I would like to display when binding "Dead" or "Alive" in place of False/True .

How do I do this?

```
<ListView Name="ListDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
   <ListView.View>
       <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
           <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Alive}"/>
       </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no

Comment: Thanks! Ill try the converter solution but you found exactly what i was looking for