# Using a DataTrigger to write 'Yes' or 'No'

Tags: wpf, datatrigger

I would like to convert a boolean value (true/false) to the texts 'Yes' or 'No' respectively. I can do that by using two `DataTrigger`'s, like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
                </DataTrigger>

            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

However, it seems that there would be a simpler (and easier to read) solution to this problem. Is it possible to create some sort of converter, use a fallback value or otherwise simplify my code?

I have tried to set the text to 'No' as default, and then only have the `DataTrigger` for 'Yes', but this does not appear to work.

Comment: "tried to set the text to 'No' as default". if you did it like `Text="No"`, then trigger for yes won't work, because local value has higher priority / precedence. Setter in a style should work: `<Style TargetType="TextBox"><Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />`; and `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool}" Value="False">` can be removed. If you want converter - create an IValueConverter implementation

Comment: use boolean to text converter you will be better off with that

Comment: If only someone had thought of this before.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to set the text to 'No' as default, and then only have the `DataTrigger` for 'Yes', but this does not appear to work.

It does if you specify the default value in a setter:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="No" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBool}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Yes" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

If you set the property locally like this it won't work though:

```
<TextBox Text="No" ...>
```

That's because local values takes precedence over value set by styles. Please refer to MSDN for more information about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence

The other option is to define a value converter:

[WPF: Display a bool value as "Yes" / "No"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no)

Or you could bind to a read-only string source property instead of binding directly to `MyBool`:

```
public string YesOrNo => MyBool ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Comment: Thank you. It sounds right, I will test it tomorrow :-)