# C# change in WPF a bool to something more human

Tags: c#

I have tried to find some information on how this is accomplished but i feel lost.

currently. my Xaml looks like this

```
<GridViewColumn Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RegRes}">
                                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="RegRes">RegRes</GridViewColumnHeader>
                                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                            </GridViewColumn>
```

the RegRes it grabs from the CaseRepo where it reads a bool from the SQL server

```
                {
                    Case entry = new Case();

                    try
                    {
                        entry.CaseNumber = (int)reader[0];
                        entry.Address = (string)reader[1];
                        entry.DateStarted = (DateTime)reader[2];
                        entry.CaseSize = (int)reader[3];
                        entry.Note = (string)reader[4];
                        entry.RegRes = (bool)reader[5];
                        entry.Ended = (bool)reader[6];
                    } catch
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Fejl ved oprettelse af sag objekt fra databasen.");
                    }
                    

                    entries.Add(entry);
                }

                con.Close();
```

How would i gracefully in the Xaml change it from displaying "true" or "false" to "yes" and "no"

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Assuming `reader` is a `DataReader`, first, consider using Dapper or any other micro-ORM that eiminates the tedium of manually decoding result sets. If that's not an option, at least use the reader functionality to index by column name rather than index (`.GetOrd()` et al.) since hard-coded indexes are very fragile. Then, use the appropriate typed methods for retrieving values (`.GetBoolean(...)`) rather than casting. Then we get to your *actual* question: turning a boolean into something else is easily done with the conditional operator: `b ? "yes" : "no"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF: Display a bool value as "Yes" / "No"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841808/wpf-display-a-bool-value-as-yes-no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a:

- **View model** which is a class that is constructed with information from the original model object (Case in your example) but has properties containing the information you want to use in the user interface (which can be text, but also information that the UI cares about but that the model shouldn't, like Visibility or Color values).
- ...or a [**value converter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) which is a class that can translate from a value of one type (bool) to another (the string "yes" or "no").

Comment: i do have a ViewModel.cs i totally forgot to get a snippet of it there as well. thank you Jesper! ill go look at the value converter interface